# Changing Text Globally on a Page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change all of the instances of "Download" in  "#DisplayDownloadButtonxxxx" to display "View" (see HTML below). I'm not sure why the code below doesn't do this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

The HTML:

```
<div class="productDownload" id="DisplayDownloadButton7476">
  <a href="http://www.website.com/7476">Download</a>
</div>
```

The Code:

```
  jQuery(function () {
    var max = 10000,
    count = 1000,
    button = 'DisplayDownloadButton',
    docID;

    for (var i = count; i < max; i++)
    {     
      docID = button + i;

      jQuery('#' + docID).text (function (idx, oldText) {
        return oldText === 'Download' ? 'View' : oldText;
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a loop, just do this

```
 $('div[id^="DisplayDownloadButton"] a').text(function (idx, oldText) {
   return $(this).text().trim() === 'Download' ? 'View' : oldText;
 });
```

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vybawxj4/2/

**Edit**

I've added `a` to the selector, this way it will change the `a`'s text, otherwise it will replace the content of the div removing the link and just letting the text.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Your terse solution works very well! :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the oldText is getting some white space try this

```
return oldText.indexOf('Download')>=0 ? 'View' : oldText;
```

Comment: Hi depperm. Your solution also worked and I learned something new about jQuery wth it. Thanks.